# What does `merge` actually do when applied to dendrograms in R?

Tags: r, merge, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have troubles understanding what the `R` function `merge` exactly does when merging two dendrograms. 
The actual question is:

How is the height of the node (merging the two trees) obtained?

The fact that dendrograms built through different agglomeration methods
can be joint as well, means that the function does not use any Lance-Williams update.
This is also confirmed by splitting the root node of any dendrogram and then reconstructing it
through `merge`: the final height is not the same as the original one:

```
# data to get the dissimilarity matrix from
mydata <- matrix(c(3,4, 9,10,11)) 

# computing Euclidean distances
dissMatrix <- dist(mydata)

# hierarchical clustering through complete linkage
hc1 <- hclust(dissMatrix)

# original height
max(hc1$height)
[1] 8

# splitting the tree
hc1_children <- lapply(split(mydata, cutree(hc1, 2)), function(x) 
                                              as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x))))

# merging the "child" dendrograms
hc1_rebuilt <- merge(hc1_children[[1]], hc1_children[[2]])

# final height
max(as.hclust(hc1_rebuilt)$height)
[1] 2.2
```

Any enlightenment is really appreciated. Showing how `merge` works on this sample data would be great.

Comment: `getAnywhere("merge.dendrogram")` and `?dendrogram` and happy reading.

Comment: I'd be happy to read and avoid bothering people in case I found a proper theoretical background to read from. I'm not saying there is not, I'm just saying I was not able to find it (if you can tell me where to find it, it'd be awesome). `?dendrogram` states that `merge` merges two dendrograms, whereas `getAnywhere(...)` gives me lines of code. The question is: Am I supposed to understand theory from code? If so, sorry for bothering.

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure and I suspect indeed that you will need to backtrace this from the code...

Comment: @TalGalili it looks like the core of `merge.dendrogram` only multiplies the height of the highest of the two (child) dendrograms by 1.1 (see line 40 of the code). Indeed, 2 * 1.1 = 2.2. Can you guess a plausible reason for that?

Comment: @DavidePassaretti - I think they just wanted some default and that seemed like it made sense. What you wrote is also written in the help file:  

height 
height at which the two dendrograms should be merged. If not specified (or NULL), the default is ten percent larger than the (larger of the) two component heights.

Comment: @TalGalili right! I missed that detail. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Made an answer out of it - for future reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is written in the help file:

> height    height at which the two dendrograms should be merged. If not
>   specified (or NULL), the default is ten percent larger than the
>   (larger of the) two component heights.